# Install Typings require for Ionic2 application

Tags: angular, requirejs, ionic2, pouchdb, typescript-typings

So I am working on Ionice2 project (still new at this .. almost a week), and I am trying to follow the tutorial below to use PouchDB for LocalStorage.

Tutorial:
http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-pouchdb-sqlite-for-local-storage-in-ionic-2/

One of the requirements is to install require using the following command

```
typings install require --ambient --save
```

Whenever I try this command, I get the error

```
Unable to find "require" ("npm") in the registry. 
Did you want to try searching another source? 
Also, if you want contribute these typings, please help us: https://github.com/typings/registry
```

Noting that I already installed Typings using the command below, what are the possible causes for this issue ?

```
npm install typings --global
```

Comment: I successfully followed the same tutorial, but I used this command to install typings: `npm install -g typings`  Not sure if that is functionally identical to what you used.

Comment: @wilburrr90 I tried that as well but same result

Comment: @wilburrr90 which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typings has been updated recently. Update to latest version of typings first.

To install require.d.ts file use **typings install dt~require --save --global**

Refer https://github.com/typings/typings for further details

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to the question, but I think it should be mentioned. The Typescript team has recently added a built in way of managing definition files. They've built the `@types` system on top of `npm`. The whole goal is that you don't need to use two separate package managers and you don't need to use multiple config files (previously `package.json`, `typings.json`, etc). Now, it's all managed within `package.json`.

If you were to install `lodash`, for example. You just:

```
npm install --save lodash
npm install --save @types/lodash
```

And you're good to go. Both are managed in your `package.json` and you won't need to use any `/// <reference-path path="blah-blah-blah">`.

Or, as Microsoft calls it, ["The Future of Declaration Files"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/).