# how to use underscore.js library in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I trying to create an application with angular 2,and want use underscore.js library in my .ts files ,for example when i want use this function :

```
   let myId = _.rest([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]);
```

`_` is not define and throw error and i dont want use   `declare var _ : any;` in my module

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to Add TypeScript Definitions for Underscore:

> tsd install underscore

Configure SystemJS

```
System.config({
  [...]
  paths: {
    underscore: './node_modules/underscore/underscore.js'
  }
});
```

Finally import the Module

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';
```

Comment: i tried this, but then it responds with 'node_modules/underscore/underscore.js as "underscore"'

Answer (score 103):

For a project based on https://cli.angular.io, I needed to do the following:

1) Import libraries

```
npm install underscore --save
npm install @types/underscore --save
```

2) in tsconfig.app.json, add underscore to array 'types':

```
"types": [
  "underscore"
]
```

3) In any component file I need to use underscore, I add this

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';
```

4) then I can use:

```
console.log('now: ', _.now());
```

and all functions of http://underscorejs.org

Comment: Worked for my webpack project. Thanks

Comment: Worked for Ionic 3 project. Just skipped Step 2 and it works.

Answer (score 6):

Check this repo. It has an example for underscore

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs#adding-underscore-library-to-your-project

I did this on my imports to make it work

```
//Place this at the top near your imports
/// <reference path="../../../../typings/globals/underscore/index.d.ts" />
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import * as _ from 'underscore';
```

Make sure you have the right reference path to underscore typings.

Answer (score 5):

For a project based on the [angular2-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed), I needed to:

1. Install underscore package:

   ```
   npm install underscore --save
   ```
2. Add following to typings.json under globalDependencies:

   ```
   "underscore": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/underscore",
   ```
3. Add following under project.config.ts:

   ```
   this.SYSTEM_CONFIG_DEV.paths['underscore'] =
       `${this.APP_BASE}node_modules/underscore`;
   this.SYSTEM_BUILDER_CONFIG.packages['underscore'] = {
       main: 'underscore.js',
       defaultExtension: 'js'
   };
   ```
4. Import "_" in my ts files:

   ```
   import * as _ from 'underscore';
   ```

Answer (score 4):

## Underscore for  Angular 4

I have included this library for Angular 4.0.2 using this way:

```
npm install underscore --save
npm install @types/underscore --save
```

systemjs.config.js

```
map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      'app': 'app',
     .....
   // other libraries
      'rxjs':        'npm:rxjs',
      'underscore':  'npm:/underscore/underscore.js'  
 }
```

Finally:

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';
```

Comment: and for webpack applications?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install underscore.d.ts typings in your project to use its js library. Check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444238/install-typings-require-for-ionic2-application/37453282#37453282) to know how to include typings